# can Mac Mail using me.com send from my business email address instead of me.com address?

Tags: email, apple-mail

can I have Mac Mail using me.com send from my business email address instead of me.com address?

Annoying that I use me.com to sync between all of my apple devices but my work emails come from my me.com account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Mail's account information/email address box, add any extra addresses you might want to send from as a comma-separated list.  Thereafter, Compose windows' From address box will have a dropdown listing each of those addresses.

I use this with another IMAP provider but I don't see any reason why it would be provider sensitive.  See [this link](http://whatevermatt.com/?p=1)

Comment: thanks but I am too late: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4632

Comment: Try it anyway. I believe this feature is entirely supported in the client and doesn't depend on or interact with a mail provider's alias feature. I.e., you should be able include, f/ex, you(at)yahoo.com, yourself(at)yourbiz.com, etc., using your me.com account. The mail would still be set by me.com, but the From address could be any of the alternative ones you set up.  Literally speaking, this is spoofing the From address, but it's trivial to do and therefore a common practice. Anyone who cares to could read the headers and tell that it was posted from me.com, ...

Comment: ... but they'd have to make an effort to do so.  Having yourself(at)yourbiz.com in the From address makes the point that this is a business communication rather than a personal one.